# A characterization of functions of bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions, bounded-variation

I'm following a lecture note about functions of bounded variation. Below is an exposition of my understanding. I have no question, but I'm very happy to receive your suggestion.

---

Let $f:[a, b] \to \mathbb R$. We define the variation of $f$ on $[a, b]$ by
$$
\operatorname{Var}_{[a, b]} f := \sup \left \{ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} |f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i) | : a=x_1 \le x_2 \le \cdots \le x_n = b \right \}.
$$

If $\operatorname{Var}_{[a, b]} f < \infty$, $f$ is said to have bounded variation. Clearly, $\operatorname{Var}_{[a, b]} f \ge |f(b)-f(a)|$.

> **Lemma** $\operatorname{Var}_{[a, b]} f = \operatorname{Var}_{[a, x]} f + \operatorname{Var}_{[x, b]} f$ for all $x \in [a, b]$.

**Proof** Let $a=x_1 \le x_2 \le \cdots \le x_n = b$. We assume that $x_j \le x \le x_{j+1}$ for some $j \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
& \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} |f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i) | \\
\le &\left [ \sum_{i=1}^{j-1} |f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i) | + |x-x_j | \right ]+ \left [ |x_{j+1}-x| +  \sum_{i=j+1}^{n-1} |f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i) | + |x-x_j | \right ] \\
\le &\operatorname{Var}_{[a, x]} f + \operatorname{Var}_{[x, b]} f.
\end{align}
$$

It follows that $\operatorname{Var}_{[a, b]} f \le \operatorname{Var}_{[a, x]} f + \operatorname{Var}_{[x, b]} f$. Let's prove the reverse inequality. Fix $\varepsilon >0$. There exist
$$
a=x_1 \le x_2 \le \cdots \le x_n = x=x'_1 \le x'_2 \le \cdots \le x'_m = b
$$
such that
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}_{[a, x]} f &\le \varepsilon + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} |f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i) |,  \\
\operatorname{Var}_{[x, b]} f &\le \varepsilon + \sum_{i=1}^{m-1} |f(x'_{i+1}) - f(x'_i) | .
\end{align}
$$

Clearly, $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n = x_1', \ldots, x'_m\}$ forms a partition of $[a, b]$. Hence
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} |f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i) | + \sum_{i=1}^{m-1} |f(x'_{i+1}) - f(x'_i) | \le \operatorname{Var}_{[a, b]} f.
$$

So
$$
\operatorname{Var}_{[a, x]} f + \operatorname{Var}_{[x, b]} f \le 2 \varepsilon +\operatorname{Var}_{[a, b]} f.
$$

The claim then follows by taking the limit $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$. $\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

Now comes our main theorem that characterizes functions of bounded variation.

> **Theorem** Let $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is of bounded variation if and only if there exists non-decreasing functions $f_1, f_2:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f=f_1-$ $f_2$. Moreover, $f_1, f_2$ can be chosen such that
> $$
> \operatorname{Var}_{[a, b]} f = f_1(b)-f_1(a)+f_2(b)-f_2(a).
> $$

**Proof** For $a \le x \le y \le b$, we have by the **Lemma** that
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}_{[a, y]} f \pm f(y) &= \operatorname{Var}_{[a, x]} f + \operatorname{Var}_{[x, y]} f  \pm f(y) \\
&\ge \operatorname{Var}_{[a, x]} f + |f(y) - f(x)|  \pm f(y) \\
&\ge \operatorname{Var}_{[a, x]} \pm f (x).
\end{align}
$$

- Let $f$ be of bounded variation. Let $f_1 (x) := \frac{\operatorname{Var}_{[a, x]} f + f(x)}{2}$ and $f_2 (x) := \frac{\operatorname{Var}_{[a, x]} f - f(x)}{2}$ for all $x \in [a, b]$. Then $f_1, f_2$ are real-valued and non-decreasing. The claim then follows easily.
- Let  $f_1, f_2:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be non-decreasing such that $f=f_1-$ $f_2$. We have
  $$
  \begin{align}
  \operatorname{Var}_{[a, b]} f &= \operatorname{Var}_{[a, b]} (f_1-f_2) \\
  &\le \operatorname{Var}_{[a, b]} f_1 + \operatorname{Var}_{[a, b]} f_2 \\
  &= (f_1 (b) - f_1 (a)) + (f_2 (b) - f_2 (a)) < \infty.
  \end{align}
  $$

This completes the proof. $\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$