# Let $f$ be of bounded variation. Then $f$ is continuous at $c$ IFF its variation $V$ is continuous at $c$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, bounded-variation

Let $f:[a, b] \to \mathbb R$ and $V:[a, b] \to \mathbb R \cup \{+\infty\}$ be such that $V(x) := \operatorname{Var}_{[a, x]} f$ for all $x \in [a, b]$. I'm trying to prove a continuity relation between $f$ and $V$, i.e.,

> **Theorem** Let $f$ be of bounded variation and $c \in [a, b]$. Then $f$ is continuous at $c$ IFF $V$ is continuous at $c$.

Could you have a check on my below attempt?

---

**Proof** Notice that $V$ is real-valued.

- Let $f$ be continuous at $c$. By symmetry, it suffices to prove $V$ is right continuous at $c$.

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. There is $\delta>0$ such that $0 < x-c<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(c)| <\varepsilon$. There is a partition $c=x_1 < x_2 < \cdots < x_n = b$ of $[c, b]$ such that
$$
\operatorname{Var}_{[c, b]} f < \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} |f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)| + \varepsilon.
$$

Let $c<x< \min \{x_2, c+\delta\}$. By [this lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607181/a-characterization-of-functions-of-bounded-variation), we have the decomposition
$$
V(x) -V(c) =\operatorname{Var}_{[c, x]} f  = \operatorname{Var}_{[c, b]} f - \operatorname{Var}_{[x, b]} f.
$$

Notice that $x < x_2 <x_3 < \cdots < x_n$ is a partition of $[x, b]$. So
$$
\operatorname{Var}_{[x, b]} f \ge |f(x_2)-f(x)| + \sum_{i=2}^{n-1} |f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)| .
$$

As such,
$$
V(x) -V(c) \le |f(x)-f(x_1)| + \varepsilon < 2 \varepsilon.
$$

- Let $V$ is continuous at $c$. By symmetry, it suffices to prove $f$ is right continuous at $c$.

Let $x>c$. We have $|f(x)-f(c)| \le \operatorname{Var}_{[c, x]} f = V(x)-V(c)$. The claim then follows easily. $\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

> **Corollary** If $f$ is continuous and of bounded variation, then $f$ can be written as the difference of two strictly increasing continuous functions.

**Proof** We have $V, V+f, V-f$ are increasing. Also,
$$
f (x) = (V(x) +x) - [(V(x)-f(x)) +x ].
$$

The claim then follows by taking $f=f_1-f_2$ with $f_1 (x) := V(x)+x$ and $f_2(x) = (V(x)-f(x)) +x$. $\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

Comment: Everything ok !

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you so much for your verification!